# AWS Lambda | How to get authenticated users sub

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

My application authenticates users using AWS Federated Identities and AWS Cognito.

Using the credentials obtained through authentication, users can call a Lambda function (using [Lambda.invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property), **not** API gateway).

I want to know the identity of the user invoking the Lambda function (sub, username, ect), and I do get the following JSON object as context:

```
{
    "callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop": true,
    "functionVersion": "$LATEST",
    "functionName": "name-of-function",
    "memoryLimitInMB": "1024",
    "logGroupName": "/aws/lambda/name-of-function",
    "logStreamName": "2019/08/21/[$LATEST]xxxxxxxx",
    "identity": {
        "cognitoIdentityId": "eu-central-1:xxxx",
        "cognitoIdentityPoolId": "eu-central-1:xxxx"
    },
    "invokedFunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:xxxx",
    "awsR
```

equestId": "3f2fc991-26b9-4eb6-aba9-4c15d6f8f0bb"
}

It's [apparently really difficult](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/54) to map the `cognitoIdentityId` to a cognito user.

**Question**: Is there any way to tell Lambda to add the users SUB in the context?

I'm totally stunned by how difficult this seems to be and I'm starting to think that I misunderstand something - such a fundamental operation must be possible!

Comment: You can  use  the identity token to get sub. What credentials do you have on lambda?